# Can't append in Blender

Tags: blend-files, append

I have a problem and I don't know why. The append option for my file is gray and doesn't work, but, this problem is only for my file. The append button works for all my other files.

This the file [blend file.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15101528/HouseOFHoly.blend)

Comment: I have downloaded your file and I can append without any problem - using Blender v 2.78a.
Are you sure you are in Object mode when trying to Append?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not in edit mode. I had this problem, but then I switched to object mode and it was fine.